# Dowloading multiple PDF files from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, pdf-generation

I have a gridview in which I have one column for downloading pdf files for each row.
I fire a javascript function which uses "window.location.href" to create and download PDF file from another page.
Now on Clientclick of some button ,I am calling a javascript function in which a for loop reads each line of gridview and fire click event (of the button which i used in grid to download PDF) for downloading multiple PDF files at once for all the rows.
By using this technique I am only getting PDF with the details of last row only ,that is m getting only one PDF after firing click event for each row.

Answer (score 1):

I do the following:

1. Include the [exchanger.js](http://pastebin.com/vV5bnTYn) javascript file in your head section
2. Initialize the exchanger object on page load: `theBuffer = new exchanger('dwnld');`
3. Create a javascript function that you will call whenever you want to initiate a file download
   :

   ```
    function downloadFile(){
         // you can add parameters to the function as needed to pass in dynamic data sent to the back end download handler
         data = "http://your_backend_file_download_handler.php?param1=val1&param2=val2&etc=whatever";  // send whatever data you need to the php program via query string parameters
         theBuffer.sendData(data);  // initiate the file download
    }
   ```

   Note: The php back end file download program that handles the requests can do whatever it needs to do with the parameters you send it in order to put together/retrieve the correct data/file for download.  After much tinkering [this combination](http://pastebin.com/EPkMv2qM) is what consistently works for me
4. Include this little bit of html in your body section.  I usually put it just before the closing body tag:

   ```
    <iframe name="dwnld" id="dwnld" style="width:0;height:0;border:0">
    </iframe>

    Note:  the id value assigned to the iframe is the same value given in step 2 when initializing.
   ```

**The result** is that the user never leaves the current page to download any number of files because the actual download is handled in a separate page (aka the iframe).  I have used it without issue in all of my projects for years now.

Comment: What should be in my `"http://your_backend_file_download_handler.php`? What should it do?

Comment: @thomas the backend handler would be exactly the php code I placed in my answer to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131797/adding-header-will-not-make-a-file-download/18131908?noredirect=1#comment26554996_18131908

Comment: I've enclosed in a jQuery document.ready function a click function attached to my `<a>` that has `new exchanger` and then calls the `downloadfile()` function.  I put the iFrame at the bottom as suggested. But when i click the `<a>` the browser still goes to the file. Any ideas why?

Comment: In your click handler you need to stop the default action of clicking on the href with preventDefault:  http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention, I added that as well.

Comment: This is actually how I have it set up. Does is look correct? http://jsfiddle.net/vARwx/

Comment: Working now. Typo -_- Thanks for the help and the extension!

Comment: @thomas Great!  Can I get an upvote or a selected answer for your question that references this one?  Thanks :-)