# How to upload files named in cyrillic which conserve their names after the upload (PHP)?

Tags: php, file-upload, cyrillic

I am uploading files which names are in cyrillic. But when I open the directory where I have saved this files , its names arent the same and are composed by very strange caracters РћР±СЏРІР°. My php file is encoded in UTF - 8 here is the code of the uploading:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'] , 'test'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$_FILES['picture']['name'])){

                    echo "File uploaded successfully";

}
```

Here is all the code of the PHP file:

http://pastebin.com/eVL7QHFF

Comment: you should not use the orginal file name, this leads to many security and other problems. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17866898/151097

Comment: I am making a school project and they want it this way . So how to conserve the original name of the file when they are written in cyrillic?

Comment: no wonder the internet is full of crapy sites with security hohles big as ....., if they learn you sh** in school. :(

Comment: but for the sake of the question... you could try to `utf8_decode` the filename. depends on your system setting.

Comment: And how to do the utf8_decode ?

Comment: `if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'] , 'test'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.utf8_decode($_FILES['picture']['name']))){`

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me

```
$fileName = iconv("utf-8","cp1251",  $fileName);
```