# Detect if Filename is empty

Tags: php

How to detect in PHP if uploaded image is empty?

Comment: ``$_FILES['file']['size']`` refers to the size of the image in bytes and not the length of the filename. For this you should use ``strlen($_FILES['file']['name'])``.

Comment: if (isset($_FILES['file'])) ?

Comment: An error code of "4" can also be returned if no file is uploaded. The 2nd condition of your if statement may be false.

Comment: $_FILES['file']['error'] == 0 will return true if the upload was successful. It's more readable to use the constants UPLOAD_ERR_OK, UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE, etc. See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Why don't you just inspect the variable? Even if you haven't configured a proper debugger, you can at least `var_dump()` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using/checking file name values:

It is **BAD PRACTISE** to use the file name given by the upload script. You have [no idea what this value can be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865860/should-uploaded-files-be-renamed) or what any user of your script will try and set this value as.

If you want to check that the file name given by the upload form is blank the you can simply use `if(empty($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){...` which will return boolean (true/false). [Read about `empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

## Syntax Inconsistency:

You have a logical inconsistency here:

```
if ($_FILES['file']['size'] == 0 && $_FILES['file']['error'] == 0) {
```

if the file size is zero this usually implies the file is `NULL` or empty or otherwise not a file you actually want to have uploaded. *BUT* `$_FILES['file']['error']` will only return zero *if there is no error*.

What you probably want is error number 4 which specifically means no file was uploaded :

```
if($_FILES['file']['error'] == 4){
    //no file was uploaded. 
}
```

[See the manual reference](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

## Example code checking file upload is ok and checking file name is safe:

As I said above, it is *BAD PRACTISE* to use the name given by the upload script and if you're going to use this value I would **strongly suggest** you use `preg_replace` on it to remove invalid characters and *then* test if empty:

```
if($_FILES['file']['error'] == 0 && $_FILES['file']['size'] > 0){
    ///file was uploaded ok, has a size above zero bytes. 

    $uploadedFileName = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-z._-]/i","",$_FILES['file']['name']);
    if (empty($uploadedFileName)){

        //sorry no file name was given....

    }
}
```

Comment: [*You're welcome...*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44162978/php-mysql-check-password-for-a-specific-username-if-username-exists/44163230?noredirect=1#comment75345170_44163230) ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- It would be a pleasure to add you to my *Christmas card list* this year....

Comment: Put one in an iframe somewhere ;-) *Joyeux Noël* ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check if is empty with

```
$uploadedFile = $_FILES['file']['name'];
if ($uploadedFile==""){
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check first if the file name is set, afterwards check if the value of the file name is not empty.

Please try the following code:

```
if (isset($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    if ($_FILES['file']['name'] != "") {
        $uploadedFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedFile);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1.

```
if (isset($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    //do something
}
```

2. > use $_FILES['userfile']['error']

see more: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php